# Can't produce required results from a webpage issuing a post requests with appropriate parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape some fields from a [webpage](https://eservices.cipc.co.za/Search.aspx) using requests module. To generate the desired result, it is necessary to choose an option from dropdown, as in `Enterprise No` and then put the search item `K2018288262` in the seachbox and finally hit the search button. [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SqAU.jpg) represents what I tried to detail. However, when I tried to mimic the same using the following script, I do not get required content within the response.

This is how I've tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://eservices.cipc.co.za/Search.aspx'

headers = {
    'X-MicrosoftAjax': 'Delta=true',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    payload = {
        '__VIEWSTATE': soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATE")["value"],
        '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")["value"],
        '__EVENTVALIDATION': soup.select_one("#__EVENTVALIDATION")["value"],
        '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
        '__LASTFOCUS': '',
        'ctl00$cntMain$ScriptManager1': 'ctl00$cntMain$Updatepanel1|ctl00$cntMain$lnkSearchIcon',
        'ctl00$cntMain$drpSearchOptions': 'EntNo',
        'ctl00$cntMain$txtSearchCIPC': 'K2018288262',
        'ctl00$cntMain$wtmkSearch_ClientState': '',
        '__EVENTTARGET': 'ctl00$cntMain$lnkSearchIcon',
        '__ASYNCPOST': 'true'
    }
    s.headers.update(headers)
    res = s.post(link,data=payload)
    print(res.text)
```

> How can I parse anything from the result page using requests module?

Comment: The web page is generated using ASP.NET.  ASP.NET makes heavy use of JavaScript including setting cookies etc. Requests has no JavaScript engine.  Try using Selenium or something that has a JavaScript engine like https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/ or PyQt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://eservices.cipc.co.za/Search.aspx"

with requests.session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).content, "html.parser")

    d = {}
    for inp in soup.select("input[value]"):
        d[inp["name"]] = inp["value"]

    d[
        "ctl00$cntMain$ScriptManager1"
    ] = "ctl00$cntMain$Updatepanel1|ctl00$cntMain$drpSearchOptions"
    d["ctl00$cntMain$drpSearchOptions"] = "EntNo"
    d["ctl00$cntMain$txtSearchCIPC"] = ""
    d["ctl00$cntMain$wtmkSearch_ClientState"] = ""
    d["__EVENTTARGET"] = "ctl00$cntMain$drpSearchOptions"
    d["__EVENTARGUMENT"] = ""
    d["__LASTFOCUS"] = ""

    del d["ctl00$btnHome"]

    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.post(url, data=d).content, "html.parser")

    d = {}
    for inp in soup.select("input[value]"):
        d[inp["name"]] = inp["value"]

    d[
        "ctl00$cntMain$ScriptManager1"
    ] = "ctl00$cntMain$Updatepanel1|ctl00$cntMain$lnkSearchIcon"
    d["ctl00$cntMain$drpSearchOptions"] = "EntNo"
    d["ctl00$cntMain$txtSearchCIPC"] = "K2018288262"  # <-- change no. here
    d["ctl00$cntMain$wtmkSearch_ClientState"] = ""
    d["__EVENTTARGET"] = "ctl00$cntMain$lnkSearchIcon"
    d["__EVENTARGUMENT"] = ""
    d["__LASTFOCUS"] = ""

    del d["ctl00$btnHome"]

    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.post(url, data=d).content, "html.parser")

    # print some info:
    print(
        soup.select_one(
            "#ctl00_cntMain_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_lblEntName"
        ).text
    )

    print(
        soup.select_one(
            "#ctl00_cntMain_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_lblPhysAddress"
        ).get_text(strip=True, separator="\n")
    )
```

Prints:

```
REVOLUTIONIZING ENTERPRISES IN AFRICA
UNIT 261 KIKUYU WATERFALL
CNR PRETORIA MAIN ROAD AND MAXWELL
JOHANNESBURG
GAUTENG
2090
```

Comment: I noticed that two post requests were issued up to the result page. However, in many cases I experienced that even if I go for only the final post requests, it help me get results, so I intentionally avoided the first post requests. My bad!!

Comment: @MITHU I tried it without first request - just directly with the number, but always got Server error. So I think 2 requests are necessary....

Comment: Yep, server error pointing to the `Enterprise No` indicating as invalid. Thanks a lot.